# Python Disctionary In For Loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to make small project to improve myself. I couldnt understand one part while I was coding.

I am scraping the data from a website and I print data with a for loop. I get the UFC links for every athlete. **System works very nice and there is no problem**. I put id for every athlete when I print them by their name. **I use a dictionary for their id number.**

The problem is when I use dictionary as; `id[x] = href['href']` **the code works excellent**

> it prints whatever I type in input(choose)

However when I try to use it as; `id = {x : href['href']` **the code doesnt work properly**

> just prints last value of the last key.

So my question is, why I cant get the **specific href** with the method of `id = {x : href['href']`

*this is the working code you can try it*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

input2 = str(input('type the name of the athlete: '))

payload = {'gender':'All', 'search':input2}
session = requests.Session()
p = session.get('https://www.ufc.com/athletes/all?', params=payload)

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(p.text, 'html.parser')

spesific_athlete = soup2.find_all('div','c-listing-athlete-flipcard__inner')
id = {}
for x, a in enumerate(spesific_athlete, 1):
    spesific_athlet = a.find('span','c-listing-athlete__name')
    
    href = a.find('a', 'e-button--black')

    #{key : value}
    id[x] = href['href']

    print(spesific_athlet.text, ': ', href['href'], '\n', x) 

choose = int(input('Which athlete do you choose(type a number): '))
print(id[choose])
```

Comment: If you use `id[x] = ...` you keep previously assigned entries in the same `id` dictionary. If you use `id = {x : href['href']}`, the previously created dictionary is thrown away, and you get a new dictionary with exactly one key. So the result only contains the last key/value pair

Comment: thanks I understand it right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use id[x] = href['href'], you're adding a new key-value pair to the id dictionary for each athlete. So, by the end of the loop, you have a dictionary with all the athletes' href values stored.

However, when you use id = {x: href['href']}, you're redefining the entire id dictionary in every iteration of the loop. So, by the end of the loop, you only have the last athlete's href value stored in the dictionary.

To fix this, you can use id[x] = href['href'] to add a new key-value pair to the dictionary, just like you did before. Here's the edited code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

input2 = str(input('type the name of the athlete: '))

payload = {'gender':'All', 'search':input2}
session = requests.Session()
p = session.get('https://www.ufc.com/athletes/all?', params=payload)

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(p.text, 'html.parser')

spesific_athlete = soup2.find_all('div','c-listing-athlete-flipcard__inner')
id = {}
for x, a in enumerate(spesific_athlete, 1):
    spesific_athlet = a.find('span','c-listing-athlete__name')
    
    href = a.find('a', 'e-button--black')

    #{key : value}
    id[x] = href['href']

    print(spesific_athlet.text, ': ', href['href'], '\n', x) 

choose = int(input('Which athlete do you choose(type a number): '))
print(id[choose])
```

Comment: I couldnt understand what you edited :) there was no need for edit but thanks for the answer :)))